# removing a defined variable from .bashrc

Tags: 12.04, bashrc

Previously I defined a variable in my `.bashrc` file. Now I comment it and `source` the file again. However the echo command still returns the previous value.

1)

```
$ echo $DB_ROOT
/home/mahmood/db-4.0
```

2)

```
$ grep DB_ROOT .bashrc
#export DB_ROOT=/home/mahmood/db-4.0
#export DB_ROOT=/home/mahmood/db-4.0-default
#export SCRIPT_ROOT=$DB_ROOT/scripts
#export SCRIPT_ROOT2=$DB_ROOT/scripts
#export STAT_DIR=$DB_ROOT/stat-manager
#export CKPTDIR=$DB_ROOT/checkpoints
#export PATH=$SIMICS_ROOT/bin:$SIMICS_ROOT/amd64-linux/bin:$DB_ROOT/stat-manager:$PATH
```

3)

```
$ source .bashrc
$ echo $DB_ROOT
/home/mahmood/db-4.0
```

The `source` command has no effect. Am I missing another search location?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run:

```
unset DB_ROOT
```

Sourcing a file is equivalent to typing out every line in it. So it serves to only set variables, and not unset them.

Normally you don't need to unset variables in `~/.bashrc` since they aren't set in the first place. In your case, you can run `unset` until your environment gets reset (usually a new terminal window will start off afresh).